# Nhibernate query to get the quantity count joining tables

Tags: nhibernate

I need an nhibernate query to get the quantity count .
here's my entities. I have a master Inventory table and a Used Inventory table.

public Inventory
{
Id,
Name,
Type,
...
}

public UsedInventory
{
Id,
Inventory,
Quantity,
Date,
..
}

I am looking for output that look like:

public ResultDTO
{
Inventory,
TotalUsedQuantity
}

please help.
Thanks

Comment: In which query API? LINQ, HQL, Criteria, QueryOver, SQL,...?

Comment: need it in QueryOver

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ, it is easy:

```
session.Query<UsedInventory>().GroupBy(x => x.Inventory).Select(x => new ResultDTO { Inventory = x.Key, TotalUsedQuantity = x.Count() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In QueryOver:

```
ResultDTO dto = null;
var rrr = session.QueryOver<UsedInventory>().SelectList(list => list
.SelectGroup(m => m.Inventory).WithAlias(() => dto.Inventory)
.SelectCount(m => m.Id).WithAlias(() => dto.TotalUsedQuantity)).List<ResultDTO>();
```